# Is it possible to dynamically close or open a Jqgrid column search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to open and close the search function of certain columns after loading Jgrid?

The underlying code allows you to hide the search part, but does not affect the search function

It works fine to hide but I haven't found what I need to do to show it

this code does not affect the search function

I have to influence the search

```
$("#gs_name").closest(".ui-search-table").hide();
```

[Sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/horusmedya/ejnrtocw/267)

**UPDATE**

The desired combination in the Client Name column

search = hidden -> search = false

search = show -> search = true

```
$("#columnhide").click(function(){
$("#gs_name").val("")
$("#gs_name").closest(".ui-search-table").toggle();
});
```

Comment: What you mean under "the search function"? What you try to implement?
 You can use `.show()` method to show control hidden by `.hide()` or you can use `.toggle()` to show or hide depend on the current state: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejnrtocw/268/

Comment: hiding and showing was super thanks, I would like to be search inactive when I hide 

Is it possible to disable the search on the back end while hiding the search part?

Comment: You are welcome! The demo, which you posted don't make any search to the server. One starts searching either by user directly, which will not work if you **clear** some field and hide it. Additionally, your demo can start searching inside of `ondblClickRow`. You can test whether `cm[iCol].search !== false` or the corresponding field is hidden and **not start sering in the case**. Do you have any other cases, when the searching could be started?

Comment: I am a stone head, I apologize I can not tell you what I want. I updated the top

Comment: As you do, before to hide the search field you need to reset (set the value to empty)  its value. In this case the search function does not post this field to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden property in double click is a property of colModel. In your case you should use the [jquery selector :hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) to do the job.

The code can be changed like this:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var cm = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var cmvalues = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
    $.each(cm, function(i,n){
        if(!n.hidden) {
            var elem = $('#gs_'+n.name);
            if( elem.is(":hidden") {
                // set it to empty to overcome search when trigger
                elem.val("");
            } else {
                elem.val( cmvalues[n.name]);
            }
        }
    });
    this.triggerToolbar();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you need to implement then http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejnrtocw/270/ demonstrates what you can do. The code uses

```
$("#columnhide").click(function(){
    var $searchField = $("#gs_name");
    $searchField.val(""); // clear the filter
    $searchField.closest(".ui-search-table").toggle(); // hide or show the control
    $(this).html("<b>" + ($searchField.is(":hidden") ? "Show" : "Hide") +
                 "</b> Client Name Search");
    $("#grid")[0].triggerToolbar(); // force filtering without a filter in "name" field
});
```

and additionally modifies the code of `` callback to the following

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var $grid = $(this),
        cm = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        cellvalue = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, iCol),
        $searchField = $("#gs_" + cm[iCol].name);

    if (!$searchField.is(":hidden")) {
        $searchField.val(cellvalue);
        this.triggerToolbar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code you gave me is very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
This code searches its data if the column is clicked

ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        var $grid = $(this),
            cm = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            cellvalue = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, iCol),
            $searchField = $("#gs_" + cm[iCol].name);
        if (!$searchField.is(":hidden")) {
            $searchField.val(cellvalue);
            this.triggerToolbar();
        }
    },
```

All the columns are retrieved

```
      ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
      var grid=$('#grid');
    var cm = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var cmvalues = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
    $.each(cm, function(i,n){
        if(!n.hidden) {
            $('#gs_'+n.name).val( cmvalues[n.name])
        }
    });
    this.triggerToolbar();
  },
```

I could not set the first code according to the second code!

I want all column data to be searched by double clicking

this is important for a practical filter

I want to do a search in all areas by doing double clicking, but I will never search in hidden columns!